# MPMoviePlayerController slow streaming : MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification takes time in iOS8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8, iphone-6

I am facing issue in iOS8, it took more time(around 4-8 sec) in MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming for iOS8 while song is played faster in iOS7

Here is my code:

```
self.moviePlayerController.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
self.moviePlayerController setContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:content.contentURL]];
[[self moviePlayerController] play];
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Prepare to play method. As it minimizes the time to initiate